# How to include the Slim framework inside the Yii framework?

Tags: php, rest, yii, frameworks, slim

I have a Yii framework and I want to include the Slim framework inside my Yii framework to respond to my REST queries.

How can this be done using shared db-connections and sessions?

Comment: Yii framework supports restful API, Why do you want to merge them ?

Comment: they were two seperate projects i want to merge together.